# SABER DOMINIO DE ORIGEN EN GOOGLE TRANSLATE API

Tags: google-api

Alguien con experiencia en la API de google translate me podria decir si se puede sacar estadisticas de numero de caraceteres traducidos filtrando por dominio (cuando, obviamente, usas la herramienta para mas de 1 dominio)?

Gracias!

Dicho de otra manera, se puede filtrar por dominio de alguna manera para saber exactamente qué gasto de caracteres te genera cada dominio?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.